# Emulating a keyboard with the Raspberry pi Issue: Bluetooth instance has no attribute 'cinterrupt'

Tags: python, bluetooth

I am trying to turn my Raspberry Pi into a programable bluetooth keyboard by following [this](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi) tutorial.

I think I have been able to programatically send bluetooth keystrokes, however I have an error stoping me from finding out.

The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./PiTooth.py", line 191, in 
    bt.send_input(state)
  File "./PiTooth.py", line 89, in send_input
    self.cinterrupt.send(hex_str)
AttributeError: Bluetooth instance has no attribute 'cinterrupt'
```

And my code (PiTooth.py) is

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#
# PiTooth allows the Raspberry Pi to act as a Bluetooth keyboard, and relays
# keypresses from a USB keyboard to a Bluetooth client. Written by Liam Fraser
# for a Linux User & Developer tutorial.
#

import os # Used to call external commands
import sys # Used to exit the script
import bluetooth
from bluetooth import *
import dbus # Used to set up the SDP record
import time # Used for pausing the process
import evdev # Used to get input from the keyboard
from evdev import *
import keymap # Used to map evdev input to hid keycodes

class Bluetooth:
    HOST = 0 # BT Mac address
    PORT = 1 # Bluetooth Port Number

    # Define the ports we'll use
    P_CTRL = 17
    P_INTR = 19

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the device class to a keyboard and set the name
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 class 0x002540")
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 name Raspberry\ Pi")
        # Make device discoverable
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 piscan")

        # Define our two server sockets for communication
        self.scontrol = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)
        self.sinterrupt = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)

        # Bind these sockets to a port
        self.scontrol.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_CTRL))
        self.sinterrupt.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_INTR))

        # Set up dbus for advertising the service record
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        try:
            self.manager = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                                                              "org.bluez.Manager")
            adapter_path = self.manager.DefaultAdapter()
            self.service = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter_path),
                                                              "org.bluez.Service")
        except:
            sys.exit("Could not configure bluetooth. Is bluetoothd started?")

        # Read the service record from file
        try:
            fh = open(sys.path[0] + "/sdp_record.xml", "r")
        except:
            sys.exit("Could not open the sdp record. Exiting...")            
        self.service_record = fh.read()
        fh.close()

    def listen(self):
        # Advertise our service record
        self.service_handle = self.service.AddRecord(self.service_record)
        print "Service record added"

        # Start listening on the server sockets
        self.scontrol.listen(1) # Limit of 1 connection
        self.sinterrupt.listen(1)
        print "Waiting for a connection"
        self.ccontrol, self.cinfo = self.scontrol.accept()
        print "Got a connection on the control channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]
        self.cinterrupt, self.cinfo = self.sinterrupt.accept()
        print "Got a connection on the interrupt channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]

    def send_input(self, ir):
        # Convert the hex array to a string
        hex_str = ""
        for element in ir:
            if type(element) is list:
                # This is our bit array - convert it to a single byte represented
                # as a char
                bin_str = ""
                for bit in element:
                    bin_str += str(bit)
                hex_str += chr(int(bin_str, 2))
            else:
                # This is a hex value - we can convert it straight to a char
                hex_str += chr(element)
        # Send an input report
        self.cinterrupt.send(hex_str)


class Keyboard():
    def __init__(self):
        # The structure for an bt keyboard input report (size is 10 bytes)
        self.state = [ 
               0xA1, # This is an input report
               0x01, # Usage report = Keyboard
               # Bit array for Modifier keys (D7 being the first element, D0 being last)
               [0,   # Right GUI - (usually the Windows key) 
                0,   # Right ALT
                0,   # Right Shift
                0,   # Right Control
                0,   # Left GUI - (again, usually the Windows key)
                0,   # Left ALT
                0,   # Left Shift
                0],  # Left Control
               0x00, # Vendor reserved
               0x00, # Rest is space for 6 keys 
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00 ]

        # Keep trying to get a keyboard
        have_dev = True
        while have_dev == False:
            try:
                # Try and get a keyboard - should always be event0 as we're only
                # plugging one thing in
                self.dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/event0")
                have_dev = True
            except OSError:
                print "Keyboard not found, waiting 3 seconds and retrying"
                time.sleep(3)

        print "Found a keyboard"

    def change_state(self, event):
        evdev_code = ecodes.KEY[event.code]
        modkey_element = keymap.modkey(evdev_code)
        if modkey_element > 0:
            # Need to set one of the modifier bits
            if self.state[2][modkey_element] == 0:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 1
            else:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 0
        else:
            # Get the hex keycode of the key
            hex_key = keymap.convert(ecodes.KEY[event.code])
            # Loop through elements 4 to 9 of the input report structure
            for i in range (4, 10):
                if self.state[i] == hex_key and event.value == 0:
                    # Code is 0 so we need to depress it
                    self.state[i] = 0x00
                elif self.state[i] == 0x00 and event.value == 1:
                    # If the current space is empty and the key is being pressed
                    self.state[i] = hex_key
                    break

    def event_loop(self, bt):
        for event in self.dev.read_loop():
            # Only bother if we a key and it's an up or down event
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY and event.value < 2:
                    self.change_state(event)
                    bt.send_input(self.state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We can only run as root
    if not os.geteuid() == 0:
        sys.exit("Only root can run this script")

    print "1"
    bt = Bluetooth()
    print "2"
    #bt.listen()
    print "3"
    kb = Keyboard()
    print "4"
    raw_input(":")
    time.sleep(10)
    state = [
                   0xA1, # This is an input report
                   0x01, # Usage report = Keyboard
                   # Bit array for Modifier keys
                   [0,   # Right GUI - (usually the Windows key)
                       0,   # Right ALT
                       0,   # Right Shift
                       0,   # Right Control
                       0,   # Left GUI - (again, usually the Windows key)
                       0,   # Left ALT
                       1,   # Left Shift is pressed
                       0],   # Left Control
                   0x00,  # Vendor reserved
                   0x04,  # The W key is pressed
                   0x00,
                   0x00,
                   0x00,
                   0x00,
                   0x00 ]
    bt.send_input(state)
```

How would I fix this issue?

The reason why I have modified the program to how it is can be found [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34086/emulating-a-bluetooth-from-a-raspberry-pi/34167?noredirect=1#comment44847_34167).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I assume you've installed all the required packages:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo apt-get update
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo apt-get install vim python-gobject bluez bluez-tools bluez-firmware python-bluez python-dev python-pip bluez-utils bluez-compat bluetooth
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo pip install evdev
```

Double check that you have followed all the steps from the tutorial correctly!

Also does the code provided in [PiTooth.zip](http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/PiTooth.zip) work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
#
# PiTooth allows the Raspberry Pi to act as a Bluetooth keyboard, and relays
# keypresses from a USB keyboard to a Bluetooth client. Written by Liam Fraser
# for a Linux User & Developer tutorial.
#

import os # Used to call external commands
import sys # Used to exit the script
import bluetooth
from bluetooth import *
import dbus # Used to set up the SDP record
import time # Used for pausing the process
import evdev # Used to get input from the keyboard
from evdev import *
import keymap # Used to map evdev input to hid keycodes

class Bluetooth:
    HOST = 0 # BT Mac address
    PORT = 1 # Bluetooth Port Number

    # Define the ports we'll use
    P_CTRL = 17
    P_INTR = 19

    def __init__(self):
        # Set the device class to a keyboard and set the name
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 class 0x002540")
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 name Raspberry\ Pi")
        # Make device discoverable
        os.system("hciconfig hci0 piscan")

        # Define our two server sockets for communication
        self.scontrol = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)
        self.sinterrupt = BluetoothSocket(L2CAP)

        # Bind these sockets to a port
        self.scontrol.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_CTRL))
        self.sinterrupt.bind(("", Bluetooth.P_INTR))

        # Set up dbus for advertising the service record
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        try:
            self.manager = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
                                                              "org.bluez.Manager")
            adapter_path = self.manager.DefaultAdapter()
            self.service = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter_path),
                                                              "org.bluez.Service")
        except:
            sys.exit("Could not configure bluetooth. Is bluetoothd started?")

        # Read the service record from file
        try:
            fh = open(sys.path[0] + "/sdp_record.xml", "r")
        except:
            sys.exit("Could not open the sdp record. Exiting...")            
        self.service_record = fh.read()
        fh.close()

    def listen(self):
        # Advertise our service record
        self.service_handle = self.service.AddRecord(self.service_record)
        print "Service record added"

        # Start listening on the server sockets
        self.scontrol.listen(1) # Limit of 1 connection
        self.sinterrupt.listen(1)
        print "Waiting for a connection"
        self.ccontrol, self.cinfo = self.scontrol.accept()
        print "Got a connection on the control channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]
        self.cinterrupt, self.cinfo = self.sinterrupt.accept()
        print "Got a connection on the interrupt channel from " + self.cinfo[Bluetooth.HOST]

    def send_input(self, ir):
        # Convert the hex array to a string
        hex_str = ""
        for element in ir:
            if type(element) is list:
                # This is our bit array - convert it to a single byte represented
                # as a char
                bin_str = ""
                for bit in element:
                    bin_str += str(bit)
                hex_str += chr(int(bin_str, 2))
            else:
                # This is a hex value - we can convert it straight to a char
                hex_str += chr(element)
        # Send an input report
        self.cinterrupt.send(hex_str)


class Keyboard():
    def __init__(self):
        # The structure for an bt keyboard input report (size is 10 bytes)
        self.state = [ 
               0xA1, # This is an input report
               0x01, # Usage report = Keyboard
               # Bit array for Modifier keys (D7 being the first element, D0 being last)
               [0,   # Right GUI - (usually the Windows key) 
                0,   # Right ALT
                0,   # Right Shift
                0,   # Right Control
                0,   # Left GUI - (again, usually the Windows key)
                0,   # Left ALT
                0,   # Left Shift
                0],  # Left Control
               0x00, # Vendor reserved
               0x00, # Rest is space for 6 keys 
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00,
               0x00 ]

        # Keep trying to get a keyboard
        have_dev = False
        while have_dev == False:
            try:
                # Try and get a keyboard - should always be event0 as we're only
                # plugging one thing in
                self.dev = InputDevice("/dev/input/event0")
                have_dev = True
            except OSError:
                print "Keyboard not found, waiting 3 seconds and retrying"
                time.sleep(3)

        print "Found a keyboard"

    def change_state(self, event):
        evdev_code = ecodes.KEY[event.code]
        modkey_element = keymap.modkey(evdev_code)
        if modkey_element > 0:
            # Need to set one of the modifier bits
            if self.state[2][modkey_element] == 0:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 1
            else:
                self.state[2][modkey_element] = 0
        else:
            # Get the hex keycode of the key
            hex_key = keymap.convert(ecodes.KEY[event.code])
            # Loop through elements 4 to 9 of the input report structure
            for i in range (4, 10):
                if self.state[i] == hex_key and event.value == 0:
                    # Code is 0 so we need to depress it
                    self.state[i] = 0x00
                elif self.state[i] == 0x00 and event.value == 1:
                    # If the current space is empty and the key is being pressed
                    self.state[i] = hex_key
                    break

    def event_loop(self, bt):
        for event in self.dev.read_loop():
            # Only bother if we a key and it's an up or down event
            if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY and event.value < 2:
                    self.change_state(event)
                    bt.send_input(self.state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # We can only run as root
    if not os.geteuid() == 0:
        sys.exit("Only root can run this script")

    bt = Bluetooth()
    bt.listen()
    kb = Keyboard()
    kb.event_loop(bt)
```

You can try to use this program and connect your mac and raspberry pi via bluetooth and see if you can use your pi as a bluetooth keyboard for your mac. You should be able to type on a keyboard if you connect it to raspberry pi and get output on your mac. Once you successfully get that functionality working, try removing what you believe is unnecessary respectively add code to programmatically type a letter on your mac via bluetooth. If something breaks, try to understand what code is doing that behavior and why. Once you do this, you should be able to advance in your project. Don't forget to start with the basics and build from there. Good luck!

Comment: The problem is I do not have a USB keyboard to type on my raspberry pi to try this. I copied and pasted that code and changed the bottom of the files along with have_dev = True. Still same error.

Comment: You can also try to use ssh from another machine to type into the raspberry pi.

Comment: That is what I am doing. Only have 1 ethernet port in my house so I am limited to how I use it (headless mode)  unless I use my Wi-Fi dongle. I also edited my comment.

Comment: @iProgram Alright, so even if you follow all steps provided in the tutorial you referenced you're getting that error? You should not have to modify anything to get the same behavior as the tutorial provides. I suggest you try to use a fresh image of raspbian fully updated using `sudo rpi-update` and `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get autoremove`. Other than that I believe you're on your own. Calling `self.cinterrupt` is an external function provided in the python bindings for bluetooth, so I suspect you haven't installed all the required packages.

Comment: Maybe try to install `bluez-utils, bluez-compat and bluetooth` aswell.

Comment: Still didn't work (bluez-utils wasn't found)

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update`? If you have fully updated your pi and you still can't get it to work with a new raspbian installation I'm afraid I'm out of ideas... Maybe try posting the question on the [raspberry pi forums](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/).

Comment: `bluesz-utils` package is not around any more (it seems to have become a transistional package) just ensure you use `bluesz`!

Comment: Sorry to bring this up again, but according to [their website](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/) BlueZ 5 removed the org.bluez.Manager interface completely. Could you explain shortly how to use this script with BlueZ5?

Answer (score 0):

It too late for a response.

Don't know whether you found a solution . Anyway i wish publish my finding here .

Follow below steps:

1. Goto /etc/bluetooth/main.conf

   And edit the line to `DisablePlugins = network,input,audio,pnat,sap,serial`
2. Restart the Deamon `sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart`
3. Make Bluetooth up and visbile `sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan`
4. Set the class to HID Keyboard profile `sudo hciconfig hci0 class 0x002540`
5. Run below Python script as super user and pair with your Android phone.

Python code Link : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sKpvOIFSZa9LWXt4y9CulOvYRTjlw1K6clgD_aDmnYI/edit?usp=sharing

And " Hello World!" spreads like a magic