# Use Raspberry Pi as bluetooth keyboard

Tags: bluetooth, touchscreen, keyboard, mouse

I'm wanting to do a project with a Raspberry Pi acting as a Bluetooth keyboard and/or mouse. 
The Pi would be connected to a touchscreen display, and I would have a virtual keyboard on the screen that I could tap on.

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B and a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and am open to using either one for this.

Is it even possible? I don't see any reason why, by creating the right signals, you couldn't make the Raspberry Pi send bluetooth signals...but I'm not very educated on this.

I've seen [this post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/34213/emulating-a-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi-issue-bluetooth-instance-has-no-attr) for the keyboard problem, but working with a mouse might be harder?

Comment: why don't you start with the keyboard project that you linked to and see if you can make it work ..... if the keyboard works, then expand it to include a mouse .......... note: if you read your post, you will see that you have not asked any real questions .... you asked two questions, but they have a yes/no answer

Comment: AFAIK `evdev` is common for all HIDs: keyboards, mice, joysticks etc.

Comment: @jsotola yea, I do see that. I'll work on it.